# Following a step in a calculus non rigorous proof

Tags: calculus

I am having problems verifying the yields part written so I wrote what I thought would be the case in red and then marked out in blue the reduced part that I cant link to what is in the blue brackets.

I am particularly wondering about how what is in the blue brackets convert to $(1/2) *B^2(t)$ and for which t?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\require{cancel}\sum_{k=1}^nB(t_{k-1})(B(t_k)-B(t_{k-1}))\\
=\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\frac 12(B^2(t_k)-B^2(t_{k-1}))\right]-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac12(B(t_k)-B(t_{k-1}))^2$$
Now
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\frac 12(B^2(t_k)-B^2(t_{k-1}))\right]=\frac12[B^2(t_n)\cancel{-B^2(t_{n-1})+B^2(t_{n-1})}\cancel{-B^2(t_{n-2})]\ldots\ldots}\cancel{\ldots\ldots+B^2(t_2)}-B^2(t_1)\\
\frac 12[B^2(t_n)-B^2(t_1)]$$
So
$$B^2(t_n)-B^2(t_1)=B^2(t)$$
Most probably:
$$t_n=t\wedge B^2(t_1)=0$$